# Convert mysql to doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony4, dql, paginator

I have the following MySQL query

```
select a.*, d.*, p.*, pow.* from appointment a
left join doctor d on d.id = a.doctor_id
left join patient p on p.id = a.patient_id
left join point_of_work pow on pow.id = a.point_of_work_id
where (doctor_id, patient_id, date) = (
   select doctor_id, patient_id,
     coalesce(
       min(case when date > curdate() then date end),
       max(case when date < curdate() then date end)
     ) date
   from appointment
   where (doctor_id, patient_id) = (a.doctor_id, a.patient_id)
)
and d.external_id = 1
```

And I am trying to convert it to DQL.

Right now I come to this version of DQL but it seems I'am doing something (or maybe more things:( wrong)

```
$expr = $this->getEntityManager()->getExpressionBuilder();
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftJoin(Doctor::class, 'd')
            ->leftJoin(Patient::class, 'p')
            ->leftJoin(PointOfWork::class, 'pow')
            ->where(
                $expr->eq('doctorId, patient_id, date',
                    $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->select(Appointment::class . ', 
                            coalesce(
                                min(case when date > curdate() then date end),
                                max(case when date < curdate() then date end)
                                ) date'
                        )
                    ->where ('(doctorId, patientId) = (a.doctorId, a.patientId)')
                )
            )
            ->andWhere('d.externalId = :externalId')
            ->setParameter('externalId', $doctorExternalId)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset);
```

What approaches do I need for the DQL conversion?

Comment: could you also add which query your doctrine produces

Comment: $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL(); doesn't return anything because it ends with an fatal error

Comment: and what happens when you remove one line after another, as far as it can be done, to find the culperates

Comment: seems that it didn't like the joins. I've changed to:       
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftJoin(Doctor::class, 'd')
            ->leftJoin(Patient::class, 'p')
            ->leftJoin(PointOfWork::class, 'pow')

Comment: But i still have a problem at the expression

Comment: Even a solution of how to pass the native query to sf paginator it helps... ut I don;t think it is possible because it expects an oject of type Query or QueryBuilder not a string

Comment: Well for native query you can use `createNativeQuery()` from the entity manager. But what does the fatal error actually say?

Comment: I know, but native query does not help me because it return the query string and I need a queryBuilder or a Query instance to pass to sf Paginator

Comment: #28 {main}  Next Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 143: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\profiles\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:54